# Rails Associations and new user signups

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations

I need to have a dropdown in a signup form that has a user can select an existing company they work for or leave it blank and add a new company later. How do I grab existing companies from the companies table to select in the dropdown, and then attach that company to the user table when they sign up?

Comment: For those kind of association in forms, simple_form (https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form) is pretty straightforward. Otherwise, I advise you to use `select`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming your users table has a company_id field and your User model belongs_to :company

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company
end
```

In your sign-up view you're probably using a [form_for](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html) @user

You'll want to add a [select](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder.html#method-i-select) and use the include_blank: true option to indicate that there's an option to not select any company.

```
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
  Other fields
  <%= f.select :company_id, Company.all.collect {|c| [ c.name, c.id ] }, { include_blank: true }) %>
  More stuff
<% end %>
```

Comment: I'm trying to make a page where user can go, see a list of all registered users, and assign a role to them(admin, author, etc) Do I just generate a view? or a whole scaffold?

Comment: That sounds like it will be a rather involved answer. I'd suggest starting a new question.

Comment: I figured it out. Thanks